# PyCharm tab shortcut

Tags: tabs, pycharm, shortcut

Trying out Pycharm. . Any idea if it's possible to have tab shortcuts? I am aware of tab+ctrl as a tab switcher, but is there any way to link a key to it's position in the tab list. That is cmd/ctrl+1 = first tab, cmd/ctrl+2 = second tab, etc.

Thanks!